# Table creation in HBase in hadoop in local mode throws exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I want to create table in HBase for hadoop in Ubuntu os .For that i dowloaded hbase-0.94.11  to run in localmode and able to start master and hbase shell command.But while i give this command  'list'    throws exception    as   "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeperconnectionexception:an error is preventing HBase from connecting to zookeeper"  .If anyone knows solution please help me in solving this issue  -Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to say anything without more details. Could you please show me your logs?

Comment: My logfile contains below content

DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster :Set serverside HConnection retries=140
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine:Failed to start master
java.lang.RuntimeException:Failed construction of master:class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HMasterCommandLine
$LocalHMaster cannot assign requested address
caused by:java.net.BindException:Problem binding to virtual machine  Cannot assign requested address

Comment: hbase-site.xml for local mode
===============================
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhosts</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>file:///opt/hbase-0.94.11/bin/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/opt/hbase-0.94.11/bin/zookeeper</value>
</property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

The log looks incomplete. But most probably the cause is **java.net.BindException:Problem binding to virtual machine Cannot assign requested address**

This signifies that an error occurred while attempting to bind a socket to a local address and port. Perhaps, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned. As a quick fix you can try this :

Change the line which contains 127.0.1.1 in your /etc/hosts file to 127.0.0.1 and restart HBase. If it still doesn't work please show me your complete logs.

Comment: I fixed the above error by assigning 127.0.0.1 to localhost and then to username_Virtual-Machine  in /etc/hosts                                      - Thanks for your reply